# Keeping relation json in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

If i have 3 tables like table 1 ,table 2 ,table 3 with one to many relationship ,with table 1 having 40000 records ,table 2 having 400000 ,table 3 having 4000000 records.
Table 2 is related to table 1 by id column
Table 3 is related to table 1 by id column

Is it better to keep documents in mongo db in a more normalized way i.e

```
Table 1 
{
   _id: "joe",
   name: "Joe Bookreader"
}

Table 2
{
   table1_id: "joe",
   street: "123 Fake Street",
   city: "Faketon",
   state: "MA",
   zip: "12345"
}
```

or should it more in a denormalized way for better performance like

```
{
   _id: "joe",
   name: "Joe Bookreader",
   address: {
              street: "123 Fake Street",
              city: "Faketon",
              state: "MA",
              zip: "12345"
            }
}
```

Comment: Second is better and is MongoDB way. Don't try to do SQL-like with MongoDB, you will run into a lot of issues and it will be slow

Comment: will it matter if there will be 1000 address records for a given document.Will the performance be still better

Comment: as long as you query on indexed fields, 1000 is ok and perfs will be fine. You will only have issue if your document grows to more than 16MB, then you will be forced to chunk it. Otherwise best to keep it in one document. Make sure you create the correct indexes on the fields you are querying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The performance really depends on how you intend to use/query the data.  But mongo is not a relational database, so you shouldn't think that way anyway.  Generally speaking keeping all your related data in a single document is best.

Having said that, Table 1 with just a name doesn't make much sense.  I would store the addressese along with the name.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB is an object store, so an object based representation is generally better than a normalized representation.

There are two considerations here:

1. Access patterns determine storage patterns. If a person and their addresses are always accessed together, then it is better to store them together.
2. 1:1 or 1:N relationships can be nested. M:N relationships ahould be stored in 'normalized' objects. In your example, M:N would mean one address belonging to many persons, and one person having many addresses. Please keep in mind that this is not the type of data-structure MongoDB was designed for, so it is a bit on an anti-pattern.